# How can I properly get the errors in unit testing laravel as well as disable csrf checks?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm trying to test my `post` method in the controller. The method definition is something like :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article;

        $article->id = $request->input('article_id');
        $article->title = $request->input('title');
        $article->body = $request->input('body');
        return response(["success"], 200);
    }
```

I've created a test which just stores the data and checks if the response is 200.
Please also show me how can I make this test better new to testing. But I'm getting `404 error` I don't know what is the error. How can I display the errors what are the setting I need to configure?
**Test:**

```
public function test_post_new_article(){
        $article = factory(Article::class)->make();
        $this->call('POST', 'article', [
            '_token' => csrf_token(),
            'article_id' => 6,
            'title'=>"hey",
            'body' => "this is a body"
        ])->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

**phpunit error:**

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::test_post_new_article
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you defined the route in `routes/api.php` such that the prefix of your particular route is `/api/`.

You have to call the full path to the API route:

```
    $this->call('POST', '/api/article', [
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'article_id' => 6,
        'title'=>"hey",
        'body' => "this is a body"
    ])->assertStatus(200);
```

Also, since CSRF should be implemented in your Middleware layer, and it's tedious and silly to add `_token` to all your test requests, you should probably just disable middleware in your tests:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class MyControllerTest {
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    ... public function testmyUnitTest() { ... }
}
```

Comment: oh thats really helpful ... can you also please help me with my error?... I've turned display errors but no luck .

Comment: @ReyYoung If you replace your `$this->call` line with the one I provided, it should fix your 404 error.